# WPF Snoop not working on Windows XP?

Tags: wpf, utilities

Has anyone else noticed that the WPF developer's best friend, Snoop, is not working on XP? I've tried Snooping Expression Blend (a WPF app) and other WPF apps too. Snoop finds them but doesn't launch the window when the binoculars button is pressed.

EDIT: I'm running obviously XP SP2 (with WPF support).

-pom-

Comment: Snoop doesn't work for me and I use Vista (64-bit Ultimate). I've heard from lots of people with similar rigs where it works fine, so I imagine there is some other tool somewhere causing issues. Maybe the same for you.

Comment: I'm unable to get snoop working as well.  And unfortunately, I can't log on as the administrator of my computer because I'm on a domain at work and don't have the password.

Comment: Just adding a comment here as well ... to point people to my answer below ... but I've modified Snoop to handle many scenarios (64-bit, interop, WPF 4.0) that Pete's version currently doesn't.

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? I haven't been running XP for some time ... but I would love to know if XP is still a problem ... after you have gotten the latest bits at http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com.

Comment: seems like snoop can't handle apps which host WPF in WinForms, like the one I'm working on. I found another person describing this type of crash back in 2006 (commect by alec:): http://blois.us/blog/2006/08/long-time-since-my-last-post-but-dont_21.html

Comment: @Yonatan Karni Just noticed your comment here. Did you ever get this working on a recent version of Snoop? I think I've fixed the bug that the crash represents.

Answer (score 6):

I have worked on and gotten Snoop to work for both 64-bit platforms and for WPF 4.0. I have also obtained [Pete Blois'](http://blois.us/) permission to make these changes publicly available and to move Snoop to [CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com/).

See the following blog articles for more info (especially the last one which details all the other changes I have made to the code base):

- http://www.cplotts.com/2010/02/14/snoop-now-supports-wpf-4-0/
- http://www.cplotts.com/2010/02/11/snoop-now-on-codeplex/
- http://www.cplotts.com/2009/12/08/snoop-now-with-64-bit-support-and-more/

You can download it from here:
http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2):

You have to be logged in as administrator for snoop to work. It is not enough to run snoop.exe as administrator, you have to actually login as administrator.

If you have the source code try changing the following line in injector.cpp

HANDLE hProcess = ::OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, processID);

to

HANDLE hProcess = ::OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_WRITE|PROCESS_VM_READ|PROCESS_VM_OPERATION, FALSE, processID);

Comment: What I have learned is that if you are Snooping an elevated application ... then you will need to run Snoop with elevated permissions as well.

I have never seen a situation where you actually have to login as an admin. That is very curious. I would love to hear more about this. Better yet ... go start a discussion in the discussion area at http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com.

Answer (score 2):

Snoop doesn't work on 64 bit platforms.
Is your XP 64 bit?

Answer (score 1):

Snoop will work on 64 bit systems.  You just have to compile your executable to run in 32bit mode.

If using .NET, you can use the .NET tool corflags /32bit+ [executable] to mark your executable as 32 bit w/o recompiling.

Comment: This is what I was doing for a while (marking the application that I wanted to Snoop as 32-bit) ... and then eventually I got ticked off ... and fixed this.

Answer (score 1):

There is another tool to inspect a running WPF application called **WPF Inspector**.
It also includes some other nice features like trigger-debugging or a data context view.

You can download it from here: http://www.wpftutorial.net/inspector.html

Greetings
Christian